# Sublimelinter-clang

Tags: c, sublime-text-3, clang

Пытаюсь добиться, чтобы Sublime Text 3 автоматически отмечал ошибки в С-коде.

Установил плагины Sublimelinter и SublimeLinter-contrib-clang.
Clang доступен из консоли командой `clang-4.0`, С файлы собирает и запускает.
Однако ошибок Sublime не отмечает, на нажатие кнопки "show errors" не реагирует, т.е. как будто и не ставил плагин.

Настройки SublimeLinter оставил стандартными.

В `/usr/bin/` лежат символические ссылки `clang-4.0` и `clang-3.9`.

Не понимаю, что может быть не так. Причем плагин не работает молча, никаких ошибок, что исправлять не понятно.

Comment: Добавил в PATH путь к исполняемому файлу clang, теперь sublime делает что нужно для cpp файлов. Почему нельзя было добавить в usr/bin символическую ссылку, не понимаю.
 С .c файлами так и не работает(

Answer (score 1):

Добавил в `PATH` путь к исполняемому файлу `clang`, теперь Sublime делает что нужно для `cpp` файлов. Почему нельзя было добавить в `usr/bin` символическую ссылку, не понимаю. С `.C` файлами так и не работает.